# C# - Editing Listbox Items

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, listboxitems

I'm making an app in Windows Forms that simulates a Point of Sales. I'm creating now the part where the user clicks on a product button and it adds to a listbox an item like this: "'Quantity' - 'Name of the product' - 'cost'".

When the button is clicked again is supposed to edit the item like this: "'Quantity+1' - 'Name of the product' - 'cost*2'".
However it just add another item with that information.

So far, my code is the following:

```
private void bprod1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        MySqlCommand cmdp1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT preco_unitario FROM produtos where designacao='" + bprod1.Text + "';", mConn);
        mConn.Open();
        MySqlDataReader drp1 = cmdp1.ExecuteReader();
        drp1.Read();
        string getpreco1 = drp1["preco_unitario"].ToString();
        mConn.Close();
        quant1 = quant1 + 1;
        var preco1tot = quant1 * Convert.ToDecimal(getpreco1);
        var text1 = quant1.ToString() + " - " + bprod1.Text + " - " + preco1tot.ToString();
        listvenda.Items.Add(text1);            
    }
```

bprod1 is my button. quant1 starts with value 0. getpreco1 is the value I get from the database (product's cost).

My objective is, when clicked the second time and so on, increase the quantity and add the cost without creating a new item.
I could just delete the item and add another one with the new info, but I want the item to be in the same place as the other, and not on the end of the list.

I appreciate any suggestions and help.
Hope you guys understand what I intend to do.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET WebForms or WindowsForms?

Comment: @Guilherme WindowsForms

Comment: SQL injection warning. You might want to consider parameterization here.

Comment: What item do you want to replace? Selected one, last one?

Comment: @RossBush What do you mean by that? Can you clarify me please?

Comment: @Logman I want to replace the item with the product information. That is, the item can be the first, but it can also be the fourth or the fifth, it does not have a right position.

Comment: @MiniKing17-Tiago how do you know what item need to be changed?

Comment: @Logman That's the problem, I don't know how to, perhaps if it searches for the product name in the items and select the item that contains that name

Comment: @MiniKing17-Tiago - What would your query look like and what would happen if someone typed `'; drop table produtos --` in your textbox?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway What textbox? I don't have any textbox in this part of code. bprod1.Text is a button. I have .Text because I want to know the text that appears in the button.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
  listvenda.Items.Add(text1);
```

is why you're seeing a new item every single time.  A mature application would be more likely to use either `private class` or `Model` approaches.

Create a new class file within the same namespace and call it something.  See below:

```
public class myProduct
{
    public int Quantity {get; set;}
    public int Name     {get; set;}
    public double Price {get; set;}

    public myProduct(string name)
    { 
      this.Quantity = 1; this.Name = name; this.Price = 0;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
      return this.Quantity.ToString() + "-" + this.Name + "-" + 
             (this.Price * this.Quantity).ToString(c, 
             CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
}
```

Now, where you were just adding values, you can check to see if the line exists, and if it does, operate on it.  Otherwise, add a new line. Don't bother with ToString() methods and such, as you can actually populate your listbox with a list of the new class!  It will call the ToString() method when displaying values.

```
List<myProduct> listvendaBind = new List<myProduct>();

///insert code here to build your list from the database if you havent already.  Otherwise, skip this step so you dont overwrite your list

//now the code for modification
var x = listvendaBind.Where(t => t.Name == newProduct.Name).FirstOrDefault();

  if(x.Count() > 0 && (x != null)
         listvendaBind[listvendaBind.IndexOf(x[0])].Quantity++;
  else
         listvendaBind.Add(newProduct);

  listvenda.DataSource = listvendaBind;
```

This is untested, as I'm working on another project at the moment, but should serve as proof of concept.

Comment: Supposedly the variable called "name" is for me to substitute with my button.Text? And I have an error on the "public override ToString()". It says: " return type must be 'string' to match overridden member 'object.ToString()' ". Can you tell me how to fix this error? I'm having an error in the ".ToString(c, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)", as it doesn't recognizes "c" neither "CultureInfo"? If you could help me I would be grateful.

Comment: That's because I typo'd.  I didn't include the typing in the override.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is only for learning and I do not recommended using it outside testing environment but you can do something like this:

insetad of

```
listvenda.Items.Add(text1);
```

do this:

```
bool notFound = true;
for(int i=0; i<listvenda.Items.Count; i++)
{ 
    if(((string)listvenda.Items[i]).Contains(" - " + bprod1.Text + " - "))
    {
        listvenda.Items[i] = text1;
        notFound = false;
        break;
    }
}

if(notFound)
    listvenda.Items.Add(text1);
```

but as I said it should only be temporary solution. Instead of this use [CDove solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44163480/2483065)

Comment: This is not appropriate for my project, because I plan to do this with several buttons, all in the same listbox. But thanks anyway! :)

Comment: @MiniKing17-Tiago and what several buttons have to do with this code? I understand `bprod1` is a button but if you have more then one you could use `sender` to create single function for all buttons or just change name to `bprod2` in next function etc. It's the same in CDove asnwer.

Comment: Oh ok, forget, I was reading the code in another way. You're right.